# android design support collapsible view

Tags: android

I am looking for a collapsible view similar to the one shown here

[image]

What will be the best approach?

This is the closest I found https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout
Want to confirm I am not missing any built in support for such layout?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project in github
https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

Which is under Apache License 2.0

You can modify this project as your requirement and use it in your application